# Package Control Error on Visual Studio 2022 preview for macOS monterey

Tags: macos, visual-studio, apple-m1, preview

On a Macbook Air with an m1 processor, I'm using Visual Studio Preview 2022. When I try to make a new project and restore packages, I get the following error:

> Getting restore information for project
> /Users/Project/{{Project_Name}}
>
> The operation failed due to an internal error: Could not load file or
> assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. An attempt was made to load a
> program with an incorrect format.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue. I used to have it installed on big sur without issues. but now I have reinstalled the whole notebook and had to update to monterey. and now I am facing this error. did you manage to solve?

Comment: nope, didn't find any solution. currently, using vs 2019 mac, and works fine in it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out and solved the issue. the problem was, that one of the nuget we imported used not AnyCPU. once I have changed that all nugets using AnyCPU it was working perfectly.

Also take care that all AnyCPU is set at:

- Plattform
- Plattform Target

All Projects that are included need to be like this.
In my case there was 1 single project, that had x64 as Plattform Target.

[image]